# How to pass authentication header to OData Service

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services, datajs

I am following authentication method described at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/07/21/odata-and-authentication-part-6-custom-basic-authentication.aspx

I am able to consume service using ASP.NET (not a problem at all).  Now I would like to create a plain HTML page and access the service using "OData Javascript Library" (datajs).

If I disable authentication and request for data, it works fine.  I could not find any sample code on how to send authentication header information using "datajs" (when used with OData.Request and/or OData.Read).

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Need an answer for using Windows Authentication instead of Basic, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using basic authentication as described in the post, you can use the request parameter of OData.request to pass in the username and password.

http://datajs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=datajs%20OData%20API#OData.request

You could write something like:

```
OData.request({requestUri:"...", user:"user", password:"secret"}, function (data) { ... });
```

Note that this will not work with cross-domain AJAX.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using datajs library for service integration then you can either use above method to odata service or you can use below method as shown in example.
Here I have setted headers in variable 'oHeader' and passing it using 'btoa' function which encodes credentials.

```
  var oHeaders = {};   
  var uName="abc";
  var pass="123";
  var requrl="{service path}";

   oHeaders['Authorization'] = "Basic " + btoa(uName +':'+ pass);

     var request = {
         headers: oHeaders,
         requestUri: requrl,
         method: "GET",
     };
     OData.request(request, function(data) {
               //  success block    
     }, function(data) {
               //  error block  
     });
```