# No Auth Header with DataJS Request

Tags: javascript, odata, datajs

I am making calls to a WCF service using dataJS.

As shown in the code below, I pass through Username and Password, but when debugging or monitoring the request on Fiddler, I see no authorization header or any trace of the username and password.

```
var url = "http://localhost/myServices/myService.svc/aMethod";

OData.defaultHttpClient.enableJsonpCallback = true;

OData.request(
        {requestUri: url, method: "GET", user: 'Joe', password: 'Soap' },
        function (data, request) {
            // successful
        },
        function (error) {
            // error
        }
)
```

The reason I need to get the username and password is so I can use it in my custom basic authentication module.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In most HTTP Authentication schemes, the client doesn't send credentials until the server challenges the client to provide such credentials using a HTTP/401 challenge with an WWW-Authenticate header that outlines what auth schemes the server is willing to accept.

Comment: don't you mean OData.read( { ... } ); ?

Comment: solution to this problem is to pass username and password in headers refer this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44021121/6396645)